# odata v4, List<> Property without expand

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

Is it possible in odata4 to create a model such as:

```
    public class PuppyDogs
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Bone> Bones { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bone
    {
        public string ChewType { get; set; }

        public int Numberofchews { get; set; }        

    }
```

And the controller class looks like

```
public class PuppyDogController : ODataController
{
    List<PuppysDog> mydogs = new List<PuppysDog>();

    private PuppyDogController()
    {
        if (mydogs.Count == 0)
        {
            PuppysDog mydog = new PuppysDog();

            mydog.Name = "Fido";

            mydog.Bones = new List<Bone>()
            {
                new Bone{ ChewType = "Soft", Numberofchews=1 },
                  new Bone{ ChewType = "Hard", Numberofchews=2 }
            };

            mydogs.Add(mydog);
        }
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<PuppysDog> Get()
    {
        return mydogs.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Can I include the Bones property of PuppyDogs without using expand? By default Bones is not returned to the client.

Comment: Do you need the Bones  to be a Entity set ? If not, you can try make Bones as complex types.

Comment: Isn't the Bones a complex type? I think by omitting a [Key] in the model definition it is a complex type? Either way, the List<> property does not show up on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things nor clear in your code, for example, the entity set PuppyDogs don't have a key, the naming convention in the controller is a little wired and etc. With the following code, it can work perfectly, please take a look

PuppyDog.cs

```
public class PuppyDog
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Bone> Bones { get; set; }
}
```

Bone.cs

```
public class Bone
{
    public string ChewType { get; set; }

    public int Numberofchews { get; set; }

}
```

PupyyDogsController.cs

```
public class PuppyDogsController : ODataController
{
     List<PuppyDog> mydogs = new List<PuppyDog>();

    private PuppyDogsController()
    {
        if (mydogs.Count == 0)
        {
            PuppyDog mydog = new PuppyDog();

            mydog.Name = "Fido";

            mydog.Bones = new List<Bone>()
            {
                new Bone {ChewType = "Soft", Numberofchews = 1},
                new Bone {ChewType = "Hard", Numberofchews = 2}
            };

            mydogs.Add(mydog);
        }
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<PuppyDog> Get()
    {
        return mydogs.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<PuppyDog>("PuppyDogs");

        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, builder.GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }
}
```

Then when try http://localhost:21830/PuppyDogs, I can successfully got the payload as

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:21830/$metadata#PuppyDogs",
    "value": [
     {
      "Name": "Fido",
      "Bones": [
         {
           "ChewType": "Soft",
           "Numberofchews": 1
         },
         {
           "ChewType": "Hard",
           "Numberofchews": 2
         }  
        ]
       }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Your example definitely works - what is the naming conventions on the controllers? Do you pluralize the model name? PuppyDog becomes PuppyDogsController?

Comment: Please take a look at http://odata.github.io/WebApi/Routing-Conventions-WebApiOData5/

Comment: @sheamus what if the Bones is parent entity to say other entity like BoneType or something, would the Bones then have a key?

Comment: I'm finding the same.  If you add a [Key] attribute to Bones, then it effectively disappears from the JSON output.  So, how can you have a collection of entities with Keys?